# Using dropdown select to change link on button and web content

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use the two select dropdown.
Language:
1.English
2.French
3 Spanish

Currency:
1.USD
2.EUR
3 MXN

Depending on the situation it will change the link on button. For eg.

Selecting English and USD will give this link on button.
https://example.com/index.php?lang=english&currency=usd
Selecting English and EUR will give this link on button.
https://example.com/index.php?lang=english&currency=EUR

Can anybody guide me on how to do it? I want to do this on a php page.

Comment: There are two ways to get started. Either you create an HTML form with the two selects and a GET action to `https://example.com/index.php`. This way, when the form is submitted the query params get set accordingly, or in the onSubmit event of the form, you get its values and set the params yourself with JS. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms for more information on forms

Comment: I want to make it happen on the same page without submitting the form.

Comment: See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61305861/5759136

Answer (score 0):

You can solve like this

```js
data = {
  English: {
    'USD': 'https://example.com/index.php?lang=english&currency=usd',
    'EUR': 'https://example.com/index.php?lang=english&currency=EUR',
    'MXN': '--some url---'
  },

  French: {
    'USD': '--some url---',
    'EUR': '--some url---',
    'MXN': '--some url---'
  },

  Spanish: {
    'USD': '--some url---',
    'EUR': '--some url---',
    'MXN': '--some url---'
  }

}

function onChangeHandler() {
  const lang = document.querySelector('#lang').value;
  const currency = document.querySelector('#currency').value;

  document.querySelector('#theButton').setAttribute('href', data[lang][currency]);

}

onChangeHandler();

document.querySelector('#lang').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
document.querySelector('#currency').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <select name="" id="lang">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  </select>

  <select name="" id="currency">
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    <option value="MXN">MXN</option>
  </select>

  <a href="" id="theButton">Click</a>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think this will work but isn't it possible to make currency and language a variable and directly put it in the link like. So, creating data and putting link one by one will not be necessary.
https://example.com/index.php?lang=$lang&currency=$currency

I'm sorry but I'm extremely new to coding. Your reply will be appreciated.

Comment: I wrote extendable  code for you. I do not know all of your data. You can solve this question in various way. But this way is more generic and good for future use. I think you try to read and understand code it will be a good practice for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach to the change event and set the `window.location.search`. Beware, that this reloads your page immediatly!

```html
<select name="lang">
  <option value="English">English</option>
  <option value="French">French</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>

<select name="currency">
  <option value="USD">USD</option>
  <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
  <option value="MXN">MXN</option>
</select>
```

```js
function onChangeHandler(attribute) {
  return (event) => {
     const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

     urlParams.set('attribute', event.target.value)
     window.location.search = urlParams;
  }
}
document.querySelector('[name=lang]').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler('lang'));
document.querySelector('[name=currency]').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler('currency'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works exactly in the way and doesn't require to create data selecting each value manually.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var saveclass = null;

function onChangeHandler() {
  const lang = document.querySelector('#lang').value;
  const currency = document.querySelector('#currency').value;
  var strLink = "https://example.com/index.php?lang="+lang+"&currency="+currency;
  document.querySelector('#theButton').setAttribute('href', strLink);

}

onChangeHandler();

document.querySelector('#lang').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
document.querySelector('#currency').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);

});
```